# How to customize CXF+Aegis to generate xsd:string type?

Tags: java, xml, soap, cxf, aegis

After upgrading my service from CXF 2.4.10 to CXF 3.2.1 my client throws an exception when trying to process SOAP response because CXF+Aegis generates different type for string values.

I cannot change the client.

Currently generated type "ns3:string":

```
<ns2:value xmlns:ns3='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xsi:type='ns3:string'>myValue</ns2:value>
```

I need type "xsd:string":

```
<ns2:value xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xsi:type='xsd:string'>myValue</ns2:value>
```

Comment: Which version have you used before?

Comment: We used CXF 2.4.10.